# Electron-Bootstrap-Vue doesn't want to show my toast, and throw me errors I don't understand

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, bootstrap-vue

So I wanted to develop a desktop application using Electron. As I wanted to practice Bootstrap-Vue too, I chose the Electron-Vue boilerplate which seems really simple to use and cool. To create a new project with Electron-Vue, I ran `vue init simulatedgreg/electron-vue my-project`

Electron-Vue doesn't come with booostrap-vue, it only comes with vue. Using npm, I was able to put it into my project with `npm install bootstrap bootstrap-vue portal-vue` (Yes, I also installed portal because I wanted to use the toast system).

And after that, I modified the main.js to include bootstrap and bootstrap-vue :

```
/*personnal addings*/
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(PortalVue)
```

And yay ! Everything seemed to works ! 
But that was before I ran into a major problem :

```
 /home/kisis/ENSEIRB-MATMECA/ENSEIRB/troisième-semestre/sgbd/my-project/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621 [Vue warn]: $attrs is readonly.

found in

---> <Portal>
       <BToastPop>
         <Sgbd2> at src/renderer/App.vue
           <Root>
```

and :

```
/home/kisis/ENSEIRB-MATMECA/ENSEIRB/troisième-semestre/sgbd/my-project/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621 [Vue warn]: $listeners is readonly.

found in

---> <Portal>
       <BToastPop>
         <Sgbd2> at src/renderer/App.vue
           <Root>
```

Noooo ! Everything ran so smoothly before that :'(

Thus, this error pop whenever I want to use the toast-on-demand system of bootstrap (which is used with `$bvToast.toast` ). And on top of that, my toast doesn't even show. I think that the error prevents it from even existing.

But I had Google at least, I thought. So I searched and I searched, seeing that I was not the only one with this error. Alas, the majority of those problems were solved by modifying the webpack configuration to add

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      // If using the runtime only build
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js' 
      // Or if using full build of Vue (runtime + compiler)
      // vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  }
```

Sadly, this doesn't work at all with me. I tried everything, even ran `npm run pack` to "refresh" the webpack configuration after the modification, but this doesn't change anything. I don't know what to do, really. I would be glad if someone could help me on this one, because I don't understand at all what is happening.

Thanks in advance !